# Getting XML variable

Tags: php, xml

I need to be able to retrieve a variable from XML which will tell me if a property is pet friendly. Currently it doesn't seem to return the correct data, and because it is nested in a variable I am struggling to retrieve it (I am a bit of a novice at XML and PHP classes)

This is the relevant bit of the XML I am using:

```
      <property>
     <propertycode>####</propertycode><lastupdate>28/08/2019 11:56:52</lastupdate><enabled>1</enabled>
        <propertyname>Cottage sleeps 6, Sunday changeover, pet friendly</propertyname><longitude>0</longitude>
       <latitude>0</latitude><sleeps adults="6" children="2" infants="1">6</sleeps><clientcode>
       </clientcode><ownerid>####</ownerid><prices>
      </prices><price/>
      <siteid>####</siteid>
      <propertygroup>Cottage sleeps 6, Sunday changeover, pet friendly   </propertygroup>
     <groupID>####</groupID><groupdisplay>grouped</groupdisplay>    
     <randOrder>242495955</randOrder><propertytown></propertytown>   
     <country>United Kingdom</country><countryiso>GB</countryiso> 
     <dateadded>2016-08-02</dateadded><managerID>0</managerID>  <managername/><manageremail/><manageraddress/><managerpostcode/><managertelephone/><managertelephonealt/><managertelephonehome/><managertelephonemobile/>
      <nobooking>0</nobooking><regionname/><regionname1/><regionname2/><regionname3/><regionname4/><typename typeID="0"></typename>
<propertyurl/><propertyaddress></propertyaddress><propertypostcode/><propertystars>0</propertystars> 
<bedrooms_new>2</bedrooms_new><bathrooms_new>2</bathrooms_new><showcapacity>1</showcapacity>
<capacitynotes>1 kingsize bedroom, 1 twin bedroom + pull down double bed in lounge. Maximum occupancy 6 adults/children plus travel cot</capacitynotes>
<maxprice currency="GBP" EUR="958.27" USD="1057.88" GBP="850.00">850.00</maxprice><minprice currency="GBP" EUR="710.25" USD="784.07" GBP="630.00">630.00</minprice><mindaily currency="GBP" EUR="388.95" USD="429.37" GBP="345.00">345.00</mindaily> 
<shortdescription>------------
</shortdescription>
<cottageweblocation></cottageweblocation>
<seconddescription></seconddescription><subcaption></subcaption><metatitle></metatitle><metadescription></metadescription><metakeywords></metakeywords><changeover>Sunday</changeover><changeovernotes/><changeovernotes_html/><highlightday>Sunday</highlightday><latediscount>0.00</latediscount><lowoccupancydiscount>0.00</lowoccupancydiscount><multiweeksdiscount>0.00</multiweeksdiscount><seasonaldiscount>0.00</seasonaldiscount><daysdiscount>0.00</daysdiscount><earlydiscount>0.00</earlydiscount><lateavaildiscounts days="" rate="" type=""></lateavaildiscounts><lowoccupancy></lowoccupancy><multiweeks></multiweeks><seasonaldiscountdesc></seasonaldiscountdesc><daysdiscountdesc></daysdiscountdesc><earlydiscountdesc></earlydiscountdesc><discountnotes>       </discountnotes><discounts>
     </discounts><photos><photocount>3</photocount></photos>
<propertyvariables><propertyvariable id="variableID61839">
       <variable id="61839" order="0">No. bedrooms</variable>           <variable_trans id="61839" langID=""></variable_trans>
         <variablevalue>2</variablevalue><variabledescription>
</variabledescription><variablephoto/><variablethumb/><varcatname heading="0" varcatID="1">No. bedrooms</varcatname><varcatname_trans heading="0" varcatID="1" langID=""></varcatname_trans></propertyvariable>
        <propertyvariable id="variableID61849">
        <variable id="61849" order="0">Pet friendly</variable>
         <variable_trans id="61849" langID=""></variable_trans>  
<variablevalue>1</variablevalue>
     <variabledescription></variabledescription>
     <variablephoto/><variablethumb/>
     <varcatname heading="0" varcatID="1">Pet friendly</varcatname>
     <varcatname_trans heading="0" varcatID="1" langID="">        
    </varcatname_trans>
</propertyvariable></propertyvariables>
</property>
```

And this is the PHP that has been previously written for me, but it isn't working:

```
$properties = $xml->property;

$variables = $property->property->variables;
$petfriendly = false;

if($property->property->variables->varcat[1]){
$petfriendly =   (bool)$property->property->variables->varcat[1]->varcatitems->varcatitem->variable->attributes()->bool;
}
    $property_meta['petfriendly'] = ($petfriendly ? 'yes' : 'no');
```

Comment: Apologies for the messy XML - I can't seem to format it right on the site :/

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend loading the XML as a DOMdocument and then using Xpaths to get this data from the XML. Like so:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlstring, LIBXML_NOERROR);
$petFriendlyNodes = getPetFriendlyValue($doc);

function getPetFriendlyValue($doc)  { 
    $query = "//property/propertyvariables/propertyvariable[@id='variableID61849']/variablevalue/text()";
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    //print_r( $xpath->evaluate($query)[0]);
    return $xpath->evaluate(query)[0]
}
```

This returns the first object that matches the Xpath list:

```
DOMText Object
(
    [wholeText] => 1
    [data] => 1
    [length] => 1
    [nodeName] => #text
    [nodeValue] => 1
    [nodeType] => 3
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => 
    [firstChild] => 
    [lastChild] => 
    [previousSibling] => 
    [nextSibling] => 
    [attributes] => 
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => 
    [baseURI] => [...]
    [textContent] => 1
)
```

This does assume that the variable ID is always the same. You can of course decide to return more or different parts of the node

Comment: You can use the Xpath function `string()` to return the value directly, this avoids problems if the node does not exist. Try `var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//property/propertyvariables/propertyvariable[@id='variableID61849']/variablevalue)'))`

Answer (score 0):

Using SimpleXML, you can easily use XPath to check for the Pet Friendly variable (assuming this is a constant - which I would expect it to be).  Then if either the value isn't found or it's 0, set it to `no` otherwise set it to `yes`...

```
$properties = $xml->property;
$petfriendly = $properties->xpath("//propertyvariable[@id='variableID61849']/variablevalue");
if ( count($petfriendly) == 0 || $petfriendly[0] == '0' ){
    $property_meta['petfriendly'] = 'no';
}
else {
    $property_meta['petfriendly'] = 'yes';
}
```